# How do I get assists in Rise of Immortals?

Tags: rise-of-immortals

Today's "freebie" contest entry achievement is "Supporter" for the game Rise of Immortals, which I believe is a DOTA-style game.

I've never played one of these games before - I'd hate to impose my noobishness on some online match, is there any way to do this in single player?

If I must play online, what's the easiest way to ensure assists while still benefiting my team?  Is there a map or game mode I should focus on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other have mentioned an assist is when you damage a player and someone else kills him.

What i found to be the easiest way was to get the achievement was to follow other people and help them get some kills. I had a melee hero for doing this but i would think a range hero would have been better since you just need to tag the enemy hero and let your teammate get the kill.

For map choice the 5v5 is the best choice, more people equals more change to assist.

Answer (score 2):

Damage an enemy then let another player kill them.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a definitive definition for an assist, but in DotA or LoL an assist is granted if you damaged an enemy that died within the last 10 seconds, or if you buffed in some way (heal, sped up, etc) someone who did.